# Subclassing Firebase FUIFirestoreTableViewDataSource

Tags: swift, firebaseui

I'm trying to subclass FUIFirestoreTableViewDataSource into an Editable...DataSource, similar to that found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41497218/9900830), which subclasses FUITableViewDataSource.

The problem I'm having occurs when trying to replace the line

```
super.init(collection: FUIArray.init(query: query), populateCell: populateCell)
```

with FUIFirestoreTableViewDataSource's designated initializer, of the form

```
super.init(collection: FUIBatchedArray.init(query: query, delegate: <#T##FUIBatchedArrayDelegate?#>), populateCell: populateCell)
```

As opposed to the FUIArray, the FUIBatchedArray requires a delegate. When trying *self* as the delegate, I get `'self' used before 'super.init' call'`.

What do I insert in the delegate parameter here in order to get the superclass to act as the delegate, as it normally would?

Comment: I've had the same problem trying to subclass FUIFirestoreCollectionViewDataSource, and I ended up rewriting the whole class in Swift here: https://github.com/red42/FilteredFirestoreDatasource . While not fully editable, it does provide a method to configure a filter that is applied against the query snapshot, and should be reasonably easy to extend to include other methods to modify the data. Hope it helps.